# How do I chown recursively?

Tags: php

I want to change the owner of a directory recursively using PHP. The [`chown`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) function works only on a single file.

I know I can use the below command from the terminal:

```
sudo chown -R user /path/to/dir/
```

How do I achieve the same in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/**
 * Recursively chown a directory
 *
 * @param string     $dir
 * @param string|int $user
 */
function rchown($dir, $user)
{
    $dir = rtrim($dir, "/");
    if ($items = glob($dir . "/*")) {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if (is_dir($item)) {
                rchown($item, $user);
            } else {
                chown($item, $user);
            }
        }
    }

    chown($dir, $user);
}
```

Comment: How to set the group?

Comment: @Black By using `chgrp`, you can add it right after `chown`.

Comment: @littleibex While your function will set ownership to the files but it won't do the same to folders, an enhanced version based in your answer I am putting here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @littleibex answer, here is a version that can do the following:

Set ownership to the files and directories too.

Set group ownership.

Set the access mode.

```
/**
 * Recursively set the owner of a path to a user
 * 
 * @param string    $path      Full path of directory
 * @param string    $group     Group owner
 * @param string    $user      User owner
 * @param string    $mode      access mode
 */
function rchown($path, $group, $user, $mode)
{
    $dir = rtrim($path, '/');
    if ($items = glob($dir . '/*')) 
    {
        foreach ($items as $item) 
        {
            if (is_dir($item)) 
            {
                (!empty($mode)) ? chmod($item, $mode) : '';
                (!empty($user)) ? chown($item, $user) : '';
                (!empty($group)) ? chgrp($item, $group) : '';
                rchown($item, $group, $user, $mode);
            } 
            else 
            {
                (!empty($mode)) ? chmod($item, $mode) : '';
                (!empty($user)) ? chown($item, $user) : '';
                (!empty($group)) ? chgrp($item, $group) : '';
            }
        }
    }
}
```